# Hosting a Java website using tomcat on a Google Domain

Tags: tomcat, java, web-hosting, google-domains, external-connection

First off I would like to apologize as I am a noob to this. I have have been trying to figure out how to get a website to be able to be accessed publicly with Google Domain. I made the website with Java being locally hosted on my raspberry pi with tomcat. I can access the tomcat server home page by going to the private address at 192.168.1.29:8080 but not localhost:8080 for some reason not sure if this matters.

I have been able to access the website as long as I'm on the same local network at http://192.168.1.29:8080/MyWebsite/index.jsp and haven't had any success/stumped with what steps I should take next in regards to being able to access the page publicly. Any help or suggestions on any easier methods than what I am trying to accomplish would be appreciated.